# Data Pass to UIPickerView inside of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have `UITableView` and there is a picker view inside every cell. User can change value of every picker separately.

I need to know that which cell's pickerView is changed. For example, when user move a picker I will know that, this is cell 3.

Is there any way to do that? It's not necessary to get instant changed values. We can store it on array than send when Go button clicked that is not related with tableview.

Comment: they are `UIImagePickerControllers` being selected?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store an array of pointers to your picker views. So index 0 of your array would point to the picker view of table row 0, etcetera. Then, make sure your view controller is the delegate of all picker views. Implement the `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` method declared by the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol. That method has an instance of `UIPickerView` as parameter: that's the one which value was changed. To obtain the row of that picker view, you can send your array the `indexOfObject:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of a `UITableViewCell`. That subclass should get a reference to whatever you want to update, and then it can simply create (or IBOutlet link) to the picker and be a delegate of the picker.

So Cell should have:

```
- (void) passStuff:(NSMutableDictionary *)datamodel key:(NSString *)key values:(NSArray *)values {
    _privateWeakRefDataModel = datamodel;
    _privateCopyKey = key;
    _privateValues = values;
    [picker reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Picker Delegate Code here
```

This way the cells will handle updating your data model directly. Keeps your code much cleaner.